# Cloning Windows 2012 R2 domain controllers with KVM

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, kvm-virtualization, domain-controller, clone

[Virtual domain controller cloning](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2012/10/01/virtual-domain-controller-cloning-in-windows-server-2012/) is a new feature from Windows Server 2012 that I use because it's a very useful and simple way to add additional domain controllers to an Active Directory domain.

This feature requires that the hypervisor supports what Microsoft calls "VM-GenerationID".  Hyper-V and ESXi do, but my client wants to use KVM exclusively as their hypervisor.

So my question is :

Does KVM support "VM-GenerationID", and therefore, fully support the virtual domain controller sloning feature in Windows Server 2012+?

I'd like to be absolutely sure on this point before suggesting this solution to my client. If so, from what version onward is this supported, and where can I find a real validation by KVM on this?

Comment: It's such a trivially easy task to deploy a new Domain Controller, why don't you just deploy a new one?

Comment: Because the proccess of "cloning" is event more ... secure, easier and faster ... than the old way

Comment: It's more secure? How? In what way? Can you provide specifics?

Comment: This is really, really, really terrible.  You're doing your client a large disservice by make design/architecture decisions based on what supports this feature.  If you want to add a new domain controller, use the actual process that's been basically the same for 15 years.  These days, it takes me about 5 minutes to create a new domain controller, an frankly, this new feature isn't faster, more secure, or easier, except in a very limited number of corner cases.

Answer (score 3):

On KVM, VM-GenerationID support is currently a [work in progress](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.qemu/387810). It hopefully will be finished sometime in the next few months.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Did you know an OFFICIAL LINK what i can provide to my client to prove this point ?

Comment: That _is_ the official link!